# Notification not showing - already set chennel as well as small icon, title and text

Tags: java, android, android-intent, push-notification, android-notifications

I have been using notification on my other app and it is working just fine. I have also implemented `channelId`, but when I am using the similar code for new app, notification is just not showing up. No errors reported.

Following is the code I am using

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notIntent = new Intent(context, hk.class);
//        notIntent.setAction(BuildConfig.APP_ID + ".inspire");
        notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, ALARM_REQUEST_CODE,
                notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder mBuilder =
                new Notification.Builder(context)
                        .setContentIntent(pendInt)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.spl)
//                        .setLargeIcon()
                        .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("not_title"))
                        .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("not_text"))
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share, "Share", PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                                new Intent().setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                                         "\n\n" + "-His Holiness Bhakti Rasamrita Swami\n\n").setType("text/plain"), 0))
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(intent.getStringExtra("big_text")));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBuilder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("daily", "Daily Nectar", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription("Daily Nectar");
            channel.enableLights(true);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            mBuilder.setChannelId("chId");
        }
        mNotificationManager.notify(ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, mBuilder.build());
        Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Notification Created"); //this log is printed in console
```

I have tested using Logs and thus I can ensure that this function is called, so no problem with alarm.

Strangely it doesn't throw any errors also and very similar code on other app is working well. So, I checked the notification setting for this app and found that notification settings are also enabled.

Unable to detect what is the problem. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There was a silly mistake.

Note the following code

```
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("daily", "Daily Nectar", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription("Daily Nectar");
        channel.enableLights(true);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        mBuilder.setChannelId("chId");
```

channel id passed to new NotificationChannel and channel id set on builder are different. A bug introduced mistakenly during the update.

Happy coding...